# Is there a way to remove __bool__ method from a class?

Tags: python, boolean, mypy

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), every class has a default `__bool__` that returns `true`.

Is there a way to "remove" this default behaviour so that it raises an error when used as bool (for instance in a expression like `if obj`?

And especially, is there a way to specify this with, for instance, mypy, so as to make static inspection aware of unwanted behaviours?

Comment: "Every class has a default `__bool__` that returns `True`". That's not quite true: every class  uses its *inherited* `__bool__` if it does not define `__bool__` itself. In most classes, there is nothing to remove. If nothing else in the method resolution order overrides `__bool__`, then `object.__bool__` is used, which returns `True`.

Comment: actually if I type `object.__bool__` in a python console, I get an `AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__bool__'`

Comment: Hm, that's annoying. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) strongly implies that it exists. As far as I can tell, the use of `__bool__` or a built-in equivalent is handled entirely internally: disassembling code like `if Foo(): ...` makes no mention of `__bool__` (and I don't think written code in which it could be optimized away), only an implication that some boolean value is available for the `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` byte code. In that case, it's entirely possible that `object` simply has a non-visible equivalent built-in.

Comment: Looks like there are several "virtual" methods documented for `object` that don't actually exist in a Python-visible form. Rather, the implementation behaves as *if* it exists, with some implementation-provided behavior if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `__bool__` method and make it return a None type. That may throw an error in linting.

Comment: It will raise a `TypeError` at runtime as well (at least in CPython, which checks if `__bool__` actually returns `True` or `False`).

Comment: Perhaps you could do this:

`'def __bool__:
return super().__bool__   # type: None`

Comment: Same as above unfortunately, mypy inspection does not detect `if obj` statements

Comment: I always wish instead of binary or boolean we had trinary or tri state T,F, and ? (not set) that would solve so many problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `__bool__` and use the [`typing.NoReturn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn) type as it's annotated return type.

```
from typing import NoReturn

class Something(object):

    def __bool__(self) -> NoReturn:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: I have tried it adding a simple instance `t = Something(); if t: print("bool")` but mypy was not able to find an error

Comment: Which version of mypy are you using? The mypy documentation suggests they support checking for `NoReturn` https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html. Maybe there's a bug or magic methods like `__bool__` are handled differently?

Comment: There's also this line in the documentation that might be relevant to you: "In earlier Python versions you need to install typing_extensions using pip to use NoReturn in your code."

Answer (score 1):

One can fake an "undefined truthiness" by raising a `TypeError`, as appropriate for undefined simple operations.

```py
>>> class Scotsman:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         raise TypeError(f"The truth value of a {__class__.__name__} is undefined")
...     __hash__ = None
...
>>> {Scotsman(): True}
...
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Scotsman'
>>> if Scotsman(): print("Hello There")
...
TypeError: The truth value of a Scotsman is undefined
```

However, the ecosystem generally assumes that `__bool__` is well-defined. There is no reliable way to hint to current, common type checkers and linters that a type has no boolean meaning. In specific, `__bool__: () -> typing.NoReturn` does not hint to MyPy that a type cannot be used in a boolean context.

```py
from typing import NoReturn

class NoneMan:
    def __bool__(self) -> None: raise TypeError()

class NoReturnMan:
    def __bool__(self) -> NoReturn: raise TypeError()

reveal_type(bool(NoneMan()))      # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.bool'
reveal_type(bool(NoReturnMan()))  # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.bool'
```